# Hide/Reveal using a checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do what I thought would be a fairly simple, hide/reveal.  If the box is checked, the text shows, if not it is hidden.  I just can't seem to get it to work. I appreciate any insight.  Thanks

```css
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .Nav-Wrap {
    display: block;
}

.Nav-Wrap {
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="menuButton">
    <input title="Display Menu" type="checkbox" name="displayMenu" value="yes" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
    <label title="Display Menu" for="nav-trigger"></label>
</div>
<p class="Nav-Wrap">Test</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `.nav-trigger:checked ~ .Nav-Wrap` is not matching your current markup.
Try to place the `p` within the `div`, this should do the trick

```css
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .Nav-Wrap {
    display: block;
}

.Nav-Wrap {
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="menuButton">
    <input title="Display Menu" type="checkbox" name="displayMenu" value="yes" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
    <label title="Display Menu" for="nav-trigger"></label>
    <p class="Nav-Wrap">Test</p>   
</div>
```